# php mssql multiple connection, by mistake connect1 records updating in connection 2 even connection2 closed properly

Tags: php

Application is PHP + MSSQL. 
Wrongly update in multiple connections. 
I have two connection.

1. opening connection1.
2. doing some process.
3. opening connection2. (Note: to open connection2 we need connection1 database.)
4. doing some updates in connection 2.
5. closing connection2.
6. update and insert process in connection1. but system wrongly updating into connection2 database instead of connection1.

How should handle the multiple connections.

Comment: Please show some code, this seems wrong and at a coding level. I've used multiple sql server connections in scripts many times and never experienced any sort of issue like the one you're describing.

Comment: Having the same issue. Two separate connections. The connection is qualified each time I use it. I open connection1. Then open connection2. Then after accessing connection1 again get an error. Please let me know if you've found a solution to this.

Comment: A blog post I found that has a simple example of the same issue. My scenario is a bit more complicated but the behavior is the same: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/432001-ms-sql-multiple-connect-problem

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not specifying the connection handler in your query calls. The mssql (like mysql) libraries defaults to using the LAST opened connection as the default.

so, in pseudo_code:

```
$con1 = mssql_connect("blah blah blah");
$result = mssql_query("SELECT blah blah blah");
$con2 = mssql_connect("blah blah blah"); <-- last opened, new default
$result2 = mssql_query("SELECT blah blah", $con1); 
                                           ^^^^^---force using original connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution I think from a [forum post](http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/connect-databases-php-script-203074.html).

The comment is below. My understanding of it is: If both databases have the same host and username mssql connect just returns the previous connection using those parameters. Dumb but thats whats happening.

> Multiple calls to mysql_connect with the same parameters will only result in one resource/connection to be created. Once the first is created, subsequent calls to mysql_connect will return the same connection.
>
> Once you call mysql_select_db, both connections will point to the same database. In my development, I got around this by using the IP for the servername in one mysql_connect and localhost for the second call. This created two seperate connections, but limits the number of seperate databases you could work with on the same server.
>
> In one script another way to work this out would be to include the db name in the select statements or switch between databases using mysql_select_db just before the select.
>
> I needed two distinct connections, since I dont' want to call mysql_select_db in my other classes.

Comment: The quote you referenced seems to be for mysql, not mssql.